# Risk neutral probabilities in binomial option pricing with discrete dividends — whose argument is correct?

Tags: options, option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, probability, binomial-tree

In trying to discover more about pricing American options with dividend payouts, I found the the post linked [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24923/two-period-binomial-model-with-dividends). I notice two disagreeing answers when it comes to determining the replicating portfolio with discrete dividend payouts. @Pandaaaaaaa claims risk-neutral probabilities are independent of dividend yield, but the reasoning provided by @Quantuple makes sense. This seems to have been unresolved. Which is right or wrong? Should we then price our option according to post- or pre-dividend stock prices?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to post the arguments here, rather than have us go to a link?